# Python - How to store values from a while loop into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to get the values from my list and store them into a dataframe

```
while (rank < len(get_rank)) and (summoner_name < len(get_summoner_name)) and (tier < len(get_tier)) and (lp < len(get_LP)) and (wr < len(get_wr)):
        contains1 = get_rank[rank]
        rank += 1
        rank_list = [rank for rank in contains1]
        df = pd.DataFrame({'A':rank_list[0]},index = [0])
        print(df)
```

**My `rank_list`outputs:**

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
```

**My `rank_list[0]` outputs:**

```
1
2
3
```

**My current output:**

```
   A
0  1
   A
0  2
   A
0  3
```

**My desired output:**

```
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can append first value of `contains1` to list and then out of loop create `DataFrame` by contructor:

```
L = []
while (rank < len(get_rank)) and (summoner_name < len(get_summoner_name)) and (tier < len(get_tier)) and (lp < len(get_LP)) and (wr < len(get_wr)):
        rank = get_rank[rank]
        summoner_name = get_summoner_name[rank]
        tier = get_tier[rank]
        lp = get_lp[rank]
        wr = get_wr[rank]
        d = {'rank':rank,
             'summoner_name':summoner_name,
             'tier':tier,
             'lp':lp,
             'wr':wr}

        L.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print(df)
```

Comment: I figured this would work but I am trying to make it more readable instead of doing this `rank_list,summoner_name_list,tier_list,lp_list,wr_list= [],[],[],[],[]`

Comment: @g_altobelli - check edited answer, you can create dictionary for each iteration and pass it to list, last pass to DataFrame constructor.

Answer (score 0):

df = pd.DataFrame(rank_list[0], columns=['A'])